# WEB-INF/classes empty in Tomcat with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, war

I do not know what else can I do more.
Eclipse version : 2019-09 R
Maven 3.3.9
.settings folder , file org.eclipse.wst.common.component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="shs">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="app"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/app-war/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Web Deployment Assembly
src/main/java -> WEB-INF/classes
src/main/resources -> WEB-INF/classes

Java Build Path
app-was/target/classes

Every time I start the server on Eclipse (Tomcat) , the folder .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\app-war\WEB-INF\classes do not contains the .class files.The src/main/resources are copy to the folder but the .class files are not.
Anyone with ideas ?

Comment: Is the source folder (`src/main/java`) present in the Java Build Path, tab Source?

Comment: Hello 
Yes , src/main/java is present

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse chokes while copying files to CATALINA_BASE (especially if there are some errors in the project). Try removing the module from the server, cleaning the server, adding the module to the server again (all actions are present in the context menu of the Server View). And check if you didn't disable automatic building of the project (Project menu).